# Anchor tags not working in Google Chrome (when linking to separate webpage)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, anchor

I'm a bit new to html, javscript, and css so I apologize ahead of time for any obvious ignorance. I'm using an anchor tag so that when a user clicks on this link it will jump them to a specific div on another webpage:

**index.html**:

```html
<div class="notice">
  <h2>If you have any trouble while you're here, please <br>
  <a href="/contact.html#contactForm"> get in touch with me</a> and let me 
        know!</h2>
</div>
```

**contact.html**:

```html
<div class=contact id="contactForm">
```

However, when you click on the link, Chrome ignores the # and just loads /contact.html. But then, when you navigate back to /index.html and then click on the link *again* - then Chrome decides to pay attention to the # and loads /contact.html#contactForm.

I've researched javascript threads that use various scroll() functions - but they all seem to work when linking to a place on the same webpage. I'm having trouble finding a workaround for when the anchor is on a different page.

***UPDATE***
I've also noticed that it seems to be the fault of random Chrome plugins - as with all plugins disabled, the anchor tag works just fine. However, I can't exactly expect all visitors to the website to have all their plugins disabled.

Comment: Side note: remember to use `class="contact"` and not just `class=contact`.

Comment: Also, you always refer to the way chrome handles this. Have you tried it in any other browser?

Comment: Thanks for the Side note - I'll get that updated. And yes, I've run it in Edge, FF, IE - they are all working. I've come across some Google threads that mentioned it as a bug, but haven't found a good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to add an anchor element with a `name` attribute containing the hash string, this element may be empty. Use this:

```
<a name="contactForm"></a>
<div class=contact id="contactForm">
...your code
```

Comment: The `name` attribute on `<a>` has been identified as obsolete by the HTML 5 spec as far back as 2009 https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features